# Trigger image animation when page section visible with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link button that links to a section of my page. When it's clicked or when that section of the page is scrolled to, I'd like to add a class `fadeInUpAnimation` to the img element below below. The image should have an opacity of 0 when it begins--I guess I can just set the opacity to 0 before the animation class is added.

```
<img src="img/circle-portrait-small.png" class="portrait">
```

This is the animation:

```
@keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    /* x, y axis */
    transform: translate(0, 80px);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.fadeInUpAnimation {
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
```

I prefer a jQuery method since I already have a jQuery file, but it's not necessary.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use the onload event: `$(window).load(fn)`

Comment: When you say "when page in view", do you mean when the entire page has loaded, or when the user has scrolled so that a section of the page is in view?

Comment: Scrolled to that section of the page. I'll update the question

Comment: Does it have to be with animations? The same result can be achieved with CSS transitions

Comment: Addressing your edit about setting `opacity: 0` first, you can do this, but you'll also need to add `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to `.fadeinUpAnimation` so that the animation freezes on the last frame instead of returning to the initial opacity.

Comment: @Niche -- a CSS solution would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a function to the document's scroll event, so that it will check if your element is visible every time the user scrolls:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
...
});
```

Then, since we'll have to run some calculations, assign the window height value to a variable:

```
var wHeight = window.innerHeight;
var yScroll = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
```

And take your element's `Y` position:

```
var elementPosition = $('.portrait').offset().top;
```

Now, put it all together:

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
      var wHeight = window.innerHeight;
      var yScroll = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;

      var elementPosition = $('.portrait').offset().top;

      if(wHeight + yScroll > elementPosition + $('.portrait').height()) {
          $('.portrait').addClass('fadeInUpAnimation ');
      }
  });
```

```css
.blank {
  display: block;
  height: 1600px;
}

.portrait {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(150,0,0,1);
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(120px, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.2,.7,.2,1.1);
}

.fadeInUpAnimation {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blank">
Scroll down!
</div>
<div class="portrait">
</div>
<div class="blank">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be a good use case for the JavaScript [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) API. Although it's a relatively new technology, it has [84%](https://caniuse.com/#feat=intersectionobserver) adoption and is more efficient than checking every element's position in a scroll handler.

I'd also recommend replacing your animations with transitions, since transitions are tailored specifically to this kind of one-time intro animation. By *removing* a class that *hides* the element rather than adding one that shows it, we can ensure that the animation only occurs once, i.e., when the element is first scrolled into view. This will also prevent your elements from snapping back to a `-80px` translate if you scroll them out, without any extra work on our part.

Long story short-- if you want performance, `IntersectionObserver`s are the way to go. If you care about 100% browser support, this may not be an option for you. The 84% support is mainly due to people using old versions of major browsers. Once people and companies update, this will become the standard.

**Note:** I think the Stack Snippet is messing with this a little bit, but if you click the "Full Page" link after running it, it displays as normal. If you shrink your viewport after doing this, you can see they come in one-at-a-time exactly as intended.

```js
const intersect_opt = {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: '80px',
  threshold: 1.0
};

const intersect_observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.intersectionRatio === 1) {
      entry.target.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
  });
}, intersect_opt);

document.querySelectorAll(".box").forEach(e => {
  intersect_observer.observe(e);
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: forestgreen;
  transition: opacity 1.5s linear, transform 1.5s linear;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 80px);
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut viverra nulla at libero efficitur, non tristique felis mollis. Curabitur mollis ipsum in porttitor facilisis. Mauris vulputate magna non sapien ornare pharetra. Vestibulum ac vestibulum massa, ac dignissim justo. Nulla eu purus erat. Curabitur iaculis porttitor ex. Nulla elementum elit sit amet odio faucibus lacinia. Sed a fringilla lectus. Pellentesque accumsan ipsum id lectus molestie consectetur. Sed leo orci, vehicula nec dolor vitae, malesuada hendrerit ex. Morbi elementum ante eu sapien vestibulum, ac imperdiet velit sagittis. Nulla imperdiet ultrices interdum. Nulla interdum dui eu nisl fringilla, non facilisis ipsum maximus. Mauris aliquam ullamcorper justo sit amet eleifend.</p>
<div class="box hidden"></div>

<p>Phasellus eu ipsum eget erat laoreet tincidunt ac sit amet justo. Donec malesuada consectetur porta. Maecenas pretium urna eu malesuada posuere. Duis in sem tincidunt, tempor urna nec, vulputate eros. Curabitur ex enim, bibendum sit amet sem nec, viverra semper mauris. Aenean euismod consectetur condimentum. Fusce sit amet ante nulla. Curabitur auctor libero blandit semper rhoncus.</p>
<div class="box hidden"></div>

<p>Suspendisse cursus ullamcorper magna et pellentesque. Donec nec risus vehicula ex suscipit ultrices. Mauris et tincidunt turpis, dignissim iaculis metus. Sed condimentum orci non lectus fermentum facilisis. Pellentesque vel dignissim elit. Nullam cursus lobortis ante et tristique. Integer consectetur justo ipsum, et iaculis ligula volutpat eu. In non nisi eu ex rhoncus tincidunt.</p>
<div class="box hidden"></div>

<p>Sed sagittis tincidunt tellus, ut blandit diam molestie vel. Praesent cursus dolor nisl, et laoreet nisl mattis vitae. Vivamus porta vel lorem in consectetur. Nulla rutrum, odio viverra sodales cursus, sem velit ultrices mi, a ultrices ex tellus id ligula. Aenean venenatis dui lectus, id venenatis velit malesuada ac. Nunc ultricies fringilla sem in eleifend. Praesent dapibus eu risus et consequat. Duis felis felis, iaculis nec malesuada id, sagittis id augue. Fusce a hendrerit nisl. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed varius commodo sem sit amet dignissim. Mauris venenatis sagittis quam et pellentesque. Suspendisse potenti.</p>
<div class="box hidden"></div>

<p>Donec in vehicula orci, non mollis erat. Sed luctus elementum est, sed accumsan diam porttitor vel. Nunc efficitur malesuada feugiat. Cras tempus vestibulum odio, et accumsan erat tincidunt nec. Nam vestibulum lectus suscipit diam tempor, vitae interdum elit cursus. Fusce accumsan libero vel congue efficitur. In feugiat, nibh placerat hendrerit suscipit, sapien nisi placerat augue, sed sodales nulla lacus iaculis velit. Nunc quis eros sit amet justo interdum iaculis. Proin auctor, eros ut aliquam rhoncus, dolor risus egestas sapien, eu facilisis est purus nec neque. Sed luctus tellus et mattis elementum. Etiam tempor justo ut viverra fermentum. Quisque pretium quam nibh, ut dictum est aliquam vitae. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Quisque sit amet massa accumsan, ultricies libero quis, laoreet lectus. Donec gravida interdum mi in euismod. Duis aliquam lorem velit, sed maximus purus mattis eu.</p>
```